# AppReview in my app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, app-store, mac-app-store

Have i any possibilities handle user review?

For example:
 - Can user writes review in some UITextField, and send it after writing?(Don't found something like this)
 - Or maybe I can handle his review on AppStore(But i can't found userAppleId on apstore web page)

Comment: please show your work before ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're asking if you can provide an interface inside your app for a user to use to write an App Store review of your app.

The answer is no, you can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do nothing with the review after the user wrote one for your app. And you can not make a textfield to let the user ti review your app. What you can do is open a url which lead the user to your app's page, so the user can start to write a review by just clicking the `Write Review` button in AppStore. There is a lot of open source libs for to simplify your work to lead users to review, for example [iRate](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iRate) and [appirater](https://github.com/arashpayan/appirater).